# Xtext StandaloneSetupGenerated - file extension and key dont match

Tags: code-generation, xtext

I'm kind of new to xtext and I'm working on an already given Language. I now want to use the StandaloneSetupGenerated class but the extension used for the registry is not the one used for the files. So the setup wont match. Where does the StandaloneSetupGenerated gets this extension from, so where do I need to change the param for the generated file to match my real file extension.

The part of the workflow looks like:

```
component = Generator {
    pathRtProject = runtimeProject
    pathUiProject = "${runtimeProject}.ui"
    pathTestProject = "../../tests/${projectName}.tests"
    projectNameRt = projectName
    projectNameUi = "${projectName}.ui"
    encoding = encoding
    language = auto-inject {
        fileExtensions = file.extensions
        uri = grammarURI
```

the property file.extensions provides the right extension but is not the one used in the generated StandaloneSetup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the file extensions are configured in the language workflow

```
    language = StandardLanguage {
        name = "org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl"
        fileExtensions = "mydsl"
```

in xtext <= 2.8.4 style workflows it is

```
var fileExtensions = "mydsl"
```

Comment: I added the part from the workflow with the language definition to the question. Is this the point you meant? If so this file extension is not the one from the generated Setup.

Comment: you are obviously using a stoneage version of xtext or a old workflow

Comment: That is true, but your hint fixed my problem. Thanks.